# Google is indexing LESS.js files

Tags: seo, less, google-search

For days, it has been a puzzle to me why my new site fails to rank on a very small niche. I have been doing really well on SEO with all my previous sites except my personal site. The site is on http://www.jhourlad.com. Just today, Google started displaying my site's keywords on Google Webmaster tools and I was shocked by the result. The image below sums up what I am talking about:

[image: http://www.jhourlad.com site keywords on Google Webmaster Tools]

As you can see, Google seems to be crawling my .less files and it is hurting my SEO result. Is there a way that I can tell Google to treat .less files as CSS files and bypass it during indexing?

Comment: You need to use a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file.

Comment: thanks @vape. Would this work? # robotstxt.org/
Sitemap: http://www.jhourlad.com/sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.less
Disallow: /*.js
Disallow: /*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.less$
Disallow: /*.js$
```

Or, instead of disallowing extensions, you can place all your static content into a directory and disallow that so it's more managable.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /static/
```

You can use [`Google Webmaster Tools`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?rd=1) to validate your robots.txt file.

Comment: Is the end regex $ necessary?